# Select a column from a different row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

so I have the following table on AWS Redshift

```
node_id    power_source    timestamp
----------------------------------------------
108          LINE         2019-09-10 09:15:30
108          BATT         2019-09-10 10:20:15
108          LINE         2019-09-10 13:45:00
108          LINE         2019-09-11 06:00:15
108          BATT         2019-09-12 05:50:15
108          BATT         2019-09-12 12:15:15
108          LINE         2019-09-12 18:45:15
108          LINE         2019-09-13 09:20:15
108          BATT         2019-09-14 11:20:15
108          BATT         2019-09-14 13:30:15
108          BATT         2019-09-14 15:30:15
108          LINE         2019-09-14 16:48:36
108          LINE         2019-09-15 09:20:15
```

I am trying to figure out how long (cumulative) the node's power_source is on 'BATT'. I am thinking that I could do a datediff on the timestamps, but I would need to get the timestamp of the first 'LINE' row after the 'BATT' row (based on ts). Not really sure how to get that value though. Once I have that, then I could just SUM() the datediff.

**Edit:**

Here is the expected result

```
node_id    power_source    timestamp             ts_line_power          ts_diff(in mins)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
108          BATT         2019-09-10 10:20:15    2019-09-10 13:45:00    205
108          BATT         2019-09-12 05:50:15    2019-09-12 18:45:15    785
108          BATT         2019-09-14 11:20:15    2019-09-14 16:48:36    328
```

Any help/assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edit added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `lead()`:

```
select node_id,
       sum(datediff(minute, timestamp, next_ts)) as diff_in_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by node_id order by timestamp) as next_ts
      from t
     ) t
where power_source = 'BATT'
group by node_id;
```

This gets the timestamp *after* the BATT record and uses that to define the end time.

EDIT:

The above is overall for all "BATT"s.  You have a group-and-islands problem.  For that, you can assign a group by counting the number of non-BATT records *greater* than each row.  This keeps the next record in the group.

This is all window functions and aggregation:

```
select node_id, min(timestamp), max(timestamp),
       sum(datediff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp))) as diff_in_minutes
from (select t.*,
             sum( (power_source = 'LINE')::int ) over (partition by node_id order by timestamp desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by node_id, grp
having sum( (power_source = 'BATT')::int) > 0;  -- only include rows that have at least one BATT
```

Note that this assumes that only "LINE" and "BATT" are valid values for the power source.